# Height for UITableViewCell, containing UICollectionView with UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout calculated incorrectly on first load

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I'm having `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewCompsitionalLayout` inside UITableViewCell. collectionView is constrained to the superview using SnapKit.

After updating collectionView datasource,

```
collectionView.reloadData()
collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

are called.

For dynamically changing UITableView cell, according to nested collectionView, I'm overriding `intrinsicContentSize`

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    let intrinsicContentSize = self.contentSize
    return intrinsicContentSize
}
```

and overriding `layoutSubviews` as well

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
        if !self.bounds.size.equalTo(self.intrinsicContentSize) {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm facing the issue on the first screen appear - the the height of the cell calculated incorrectly - I only see part of the the cells, but when I'm on the screen already and reload cells, everything appears correctly.

What I observe in `intrinsicContentSize`

```
contentSize -(0.0, 0.0)
contentSize -(238.0, 244.0)
contentSize -(238.0, 244.0)
contentSize -(308.0, 352.0)
contentSize -(308.0, 352.0)
```

cell height updates to 244.0 and every other intrinsicContentSize update is ignored. But, when I'm using UICollectionViewFlowLayout instead CompositionalLayout - intrinsicContentSize updates only twice and cell height is correct.

Of course, I can calculate the UICollectionView parent UITableView cell manually and update height accordingly in `HeightForRowAtIndexPath`, but I want to avoid manual calculations.

Any suggestions, thoughts?